# Calculate Time difference between two lines

Tags: awk, sed, perl, date

grep timestamp in a file as given below. Now I need to calculate time difference

file data:

```
18:29:10
04:56:50
```

I tried following command its output is in minus:

```
awk -F":" 'FNR==1{split($0,a,":");sec1=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]} FNR==2{split($0,b,":");sec2=b[1]*3600+b[2]*60+b[3];val=sec2-sec1;ho=int(val/3600);val=val%3600;mi=sprintf("%02d",(val/60));val=val%60;;print ho":"mi":"val}' file.txt
```

Output is: -13:-32:-10

I want output like: 10:27:40

Comment: Downvoted for confusing the hell out of my debugging by including TWO wrong outputs.  Please fix.

Comment: how can you tell which day these times are for?  e.g what information is available to determine where 04:56:50 is the morning of the same day as 18:29:10, or the next morning?  or some morning next or last week?  i.e. don't throw away the date portion of the timestamp when it's still needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant 10:27:40

```
awk -F: '
  {t[NR] = $3 + 60 * ($2 + 60 * $1)}
  END{
    d = t[2] - t[1]
    if (d < 0) d += 86400
    h = d / 3600
    d %= 3600
    m = d / 60
    s = d % 60
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s
  }'
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU date:

```
string1="18:29:10"
string2="04:56:50"
StartDate=$(date -u -d "$string1" +"%s")
FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$string2" +"%s")
date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S"
```

Output:

```
10:27:40
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442175/3776858

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, using `dc`:

```
$ cat file.txt
18:29:10
04:56:50
$ tr : \ <file.txt | dc -f - -e 'r60*+r60d**+r-r60*-r60d**-60dod24**+p'
 10 27 40
$
```

This was my first `dc` script.  Fun learning experience.

---

Another approach using `dc`:

```
$ cat file.txt 
18:29:10
04:56:50
$ cat time_subtract.dc 
[r60*+r60d**+]sb60d24**sd[ld+d0>n]snlbxsflbx_1*lf+60od0>np
$ tr : \ <file.txt | dc -f - -f time_subtract.dc 
 10 27 40
$
```

---

Finally, nicely wrapped up in a shell script so it can be run as `./script.sh file.txt` or `some pipeline | ./script.sh`, we have:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat "$@" |
tr : ' ' |
  dc -e '
[60+Lm1-Sm]SS
[60+Lh1-Sh]SM
[24+]SH
?SsSmSh
?SsSmSh
LsLs- d0>S Ss
LmLm- d0>M Sm
LhLh- d0>H Sh
[
]Ls[:]Lm[:]Lh
nnnnnn
'
```