# Calculate the time difference

Tags: bash

I need to calculate the time difference

File:

```
$ cat time.log
06:12:23
06:12:54
06:14:18
06:15:38
$
```

I expect results as follows:

```
0:00:31
0:01:20
```

I tried this

```
#!/bin/sh
cat "$@" |
tr : ' ' |
  dc -e '
[60+Lm1-Sm]SS
[60+Lh1-Sh]SM
[24+]SH
?SsSmSh
?SsSmSh
LsLs- d0>S Ss
LmLm- d0>M Sm
LhLh- d0>H Sh
[
]Ls[:]Lm[:]Lh
nnnnnn
'
```

but the result is as follows

```
$ ./calculate_time.sh time.log 
0:0:31
$
```

It gets the difference between the first 2 lines only, how can I make it get the difference between the remaining lines as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [time difference using sed/awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700305/time-difference-using-sed-awk)

Comment: Mohamed when you have got an answer that works best for you, please remember to accept it with the tick mark alongside

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414725/50240

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Time difference between two lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414725/calculate-time-difference-between-two-lines)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a tool like `date` to convert to something you can calculate with?

If you don't mind the security implication of the GNU `sed` `e` flag, you can do

```
sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/date -d @$(($(date -d \2 +%s) - $(date -d \1 +%s))) -u +%H:%M:%S/e' time.log
```

So, you use `date -d 6:12:43 +%s` to convert the timestamps to seconds, calculate the difference and convert back by `date -d 80 -u +%H:%M:%S`. The sed script combines the lines and executes for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution, re-using your code using a `bash` array, feeding `dc` with a pair of time string on each invocation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time=( $(< time.log) )
for ((i=0; i< ${#time[@]}; i+=2)); do
    printf '%s\n' "${time[i]}" "${time[i+1]}" |
    tr : ' ' |
    dc -e '
        [60+Lm1-Sm]SS
        [60+Lh1-Sh]SM
        [24+]SH
        ?SsSmSh
        ?SsSmSh
        LsLs- d0>S Ss
        LmLm- d0>M Sm
        LhLh- d0>H Sh
        [
        ]Ls[:]Lm[:]Lh
        nnnnnn
    ' | tr -d ' '
done
```

```
0:0:31
0:1:20
```

Comment: What is the content of the whole script? Paste it on https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin

Comment: Highly appreciated!

but why the output is as follows":

$ ./calc.sh time.log
0:0:31
        0:1:20 $    

I mean the second line is shifted

Comment: Not reproducible on my side. I don't know what you have done maybe different in your script.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I also get the second line indented by eight spaces (not a tab)

Comment: Post edited accordingly, added `| tr -d ' '`

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
# line number
nr=1

while IFS=":" read -r h m s; do
  if [[ $nr%2 -eq 1 ]]; then
    # odd line
    t1=$(($h*60*60+$m*60+$s))
  else
    # even line
    t2=$(($h*60*60+$m*60+$s))

    # get diff in seconds
    d=$((t2-t1))

    # output diff in HH:MM:SS
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $(($d/60/60%24)) $(($d/60%60)) $(($d%60))
  fi

  # increase line number by one
  nr=$(($nr+1))
done < time.log
```

Ouput:

```
00:00:31
00:01:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all time pairs are from the same day, for example, 2023-05-06 (any date would obviously do), we can use `strptime()` to convert them to Unix timestamps, then take the difference and convert that back into a string with `strftime()`.

We can do this with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) by reading the time strings in pairs from `paste` like so:

```bash
paste - - <file |
mlr --tsv -N \
    put -s now=2023-05-06 '$tdiff = strftime(strptime(@now . " " . $2, "%F %T") - strptime(@now . " " . $1, "%F %T"), "%T")' then \
    cut -f tdiff
```

This first puts the input time strings into tab-delimited pairs on separate lines using `paste`.  Miller then reads this as a header-less TSV input stream and uses its `put` sub-command to calculate the time difference in a new field called `tdiff`.  The `cut` sub-command is then used to extract only this new field.

Given the data in the question, this would output the following:

```
00:00:31
00:01:20
```